# Add bevel to more complex objects

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I am creating a lego man and would like the legs beveled so that the edges are not too sharp. This works fine for simple objects like the body.

[image: body]

But the legs are made from a cylinder, which is chopped off at the bottom then its vertices are extruded to create the blocky part of the lower leg.

[image: leg]

Is it possible to get a bevel on this type of object, or should I create the leg using a different technique to get smoother edges?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bevel modifier ought to do the trick for you.

Simply select your object in Object Mode, and then add a **Bevel** modifier from the *Modifier properties*:

[image]

[image]

You can then adjust the amount of beveling and the number of segments from the modifier options.

**Note:** be wary of ngons. These do not bevel very well and will tend to lead to weird artifacts in the beveled mesh.

You can also specify only certain areas to be beveled via the the **Limit Methods**.

Comment: It was the ngon that was the issue using bevel for me, also using limit by angle sorts out the shading, cheers man

Answer (score 5):

Here's a way you can do this.

With a little extra work and the same basic tools it can be refined further.

[image]

Comment: This is the way I usually model LEGO Minifigure legs. Just select the edges and bevel.

Comment: I've +1 this because I didn't know about the 4th step, but I wanted bevel to work, thanks for the answer.