# Adding bevel altering the geometry and I can't create loopcuts

Tags: modeling

Q1. I want to bevel the edge. When I bevel and make loopcuts some extra geometry is made.

Q2. I have just made a simple geometry. I can't create loopcuts. I have removed doubles, recalculated the normals, yet I can't make loopcuts.[image]

You can download the file [image]

Comment: You can upload your file to [Blend-Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) and edit your question to include the link given to you once the upload is finished.

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52842/cant-bevel-an-ngon and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10865/add-bevel-to-more-complex-objects.

Comment: Also http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21287/bevel-tool-creating-intersecting-faces

Comment: Which addon have you found ? If you solved your problem yourself write an answer with clear steps of what have you done to give another solution.

Comment: please only ask one question per question. You can ask as many questions as you want.

Answer (score 1):

That geometry won't be beveled as expected because you're trying to do that on non-planar Ngon consisting of 8 vertices:

[image: screenshot of Ngon won't be beveled]

Instead dissolve unneeded vertices, and join those on the left to make solid corner:

[image: screenshot of converted Ngon]

The selection on the screenshot is an added loopcut which is better to create to avoid Ngon in the middle (however one from the right side is left which is also best to avoid).

Then there won't be any spikes because the corner will be bevelled equally in all directions.

See also related posts - [Bevel tool creating intersecting faces](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21287/bevel-tool-creating-intersecting-faces), [Can't bevel an NGon](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52842/cant-bevel-an-ngon)